# SphinxSearch or a spider - which one to choose?

Tags: search, full-text-search, search-engine

We own SiteA and SiteB and they share the same server and database where we have full control.
SiteC , siteD and siteE are some of the sites we own as well but reside on a different web hosts.

The goal is to create a unified search functionality for all of the sites mentioned above. That is if somebody search for a term in SiteA, the search result will automatically come up with results from SiteB,SiteC,SiteD and Site E too. The search results should be shown under the website they were found in.

All these websites content are stored in their own databases.

If I use SphinxSearch to index the above sites,I would then require those sites that we dont   have complete control with to setup a web service where i can download a database dump or csv file for indexing.

Im not quite sure about how a sphider will come into play here so need your opinion.

Sphinx or a spider?

THanks!

Comment: what benefits does these two tools have over each other??

Answer (score 0):

If you can ask the owner of other websites to give you content for free, then there is no need for a spider. Just use sphinxsearch to index the content.

If you can't get content directly from them, a spider is the only choice for you. There is little to think about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx is a full-text search engine solution, while a spider is for fetching contents from internet. They are not replacements to each other. Even if you use a spider, you still have to use some full-text search engine software for example sphinx or lucene/solr. 
So you have to make a decision first: Do I want to use sphinx for searching? If the answer is yes, then there is only one thing left: how can I index the contents for searching?

sphinx supports using database or XML as data source. Database as data source is more popular because preparing and updating XML documents in a specific format is very tedious(compared to maintaining a database table). So I guess finally you have to store all of the data into database. As you described, all of the data are all ready in databases, but some of the databases are out of your control. For you own database, there is no problem. For the databases that out of your control, I suggest that you use distributed sphinx searching: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/distributed.html

> The key idea is to horizontally partition (HP) searched data accross
>   search nodes and then process it in parallel.
>
> Partitioning is done manually. You should
>
> setup several instances of Sphinx programs (indexer and searchd) on
>   different servers;
>
> make the instances index (and search) different parts of data;
>
> configure a special distributed index on some of the searchd
>   instances;
>
> and query this index.
>
> This index only contains references to other local and remote indexes
>   - so it could not be directly reindexed, and you should reindex those indexes which it references instead.